# Can I run alsa and pulse side by side ? I think there is some problem with the alsa ! My ubuntu login sound and alert sound are not working?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I think I have Alsa driver installed. Pulse not working may be I dont have it installed. Not sure If I can run Pulse and Alsa. I had to configure each application prior to work which use pulse.(SMplayer by default select pulse. I had to change that)

I know a little about these. So if the question is stupid then please help me.
Smplayer always showing a cross(x) icon in front of speaker icon as it is disabled, though Im playing sound.

Comment: In a default Ubuntu installation both, ALSA and Pulse Audio are installed. Pulse Audio makes use of ALSA. Most applications are set up to use Pulse Audio. Therefore in order to help you we need more information on your system: Ubuntu version, custom changes you may have made, application in question, and more. See also [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/16241/3940).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually a stupid question. @ Takkat he is right.(Look at the comment). However if you want good control over Pulse and Alsa then you can Install "PulseAudio Preferences" and "Pulse Volume Control" from Ubuntu Software Center.

Gnome AlsaMixer also can do the job easier. If you do recordings then you must have Gnome Alsa Miser. Search on Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 3):

If Ubuntu login sound and alert sound are not working then here's how to fix it:

Download `dconf-editor` if you haven't already. Then click in this order org -> gnome -> desktop -> sound. Once in sound, click on *theme-name*. The default value is *freedesktop*. Change it to *ubuntu* (lowercase!) and exit. Log out and log back in to hear the glorious drums!!

Comment: hey if this solved your problem then mark this problem as solved and do not forget to vote up my answer! :p